# Android Maps app not finding the correct MapView

Tags: java, android, api, maps

I have made an app that uses Google Android Maps API V2 and I have followed every step in the guide provided by Google but it doesn't work unfortunely and it crashes every time I try to start it up.

The issue seem so be that it is not looking for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView which is the MapView for the Android Maps API V2 but it's instead looking for com.google.android.maps.MapView which is the MapView for the Android Maps API V1 and I'm wondering how do I change that?

```
03-04 00:26:51.274: E/dalvikvm(14369): Could not find class 'com.google.android.maps.MapView', referenced from method com.cornboyzmaps.googlemapsA.MainActivity.onCreate
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.name;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.name.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="**api_key**" />
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: `com.cornboyzmaps.googlemapsA.MainActivity` is the class that is having the problem. You are showing the code listing for `com.example.name.MainActivity`. Do you have a separate package in your app, named `com.cornboyzmaps.googlemapsA`, that might contain a separate `MainActivity` that you are trying to run?

Comment: Yes the real package is named com.cornboyzmaps.googlemapsA(I changed it too com.example.name.MainActivity as too show that it's sort what my code looks like, turned out too be pretty dumb) and it's the one I'm actually using(that MainActivity.java code is from com.cornboyzmaps.googlemapsA).

Comment: There's nothing obvious from what you have posted here that would result in this error. Try creating a separate project to reproduce the error. If you can, post that project somewhere in its entirety. If you cannot reproduce the error with a separate project, then you need to progressively make your separate project look more like your main project, until such time as the error re-surfaces or your separate project has all the right code (in which case, just switch your development to the separate project).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just inflating the xml layout normally with setContentView? Right now it looks like you're trying to make a fragment from an xml fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In activity_main.xml you shouldn't have a map fragment, since you add it programatically.
What I would do would be to change activity_mail.xml to contain a Framelayout that will be the fragment container. So for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

after that in MainActivity.java you should findViewbyId for the Framelayout and add the mapfragment.
Also it is strange that you get an error for MapView but there isn't one in your code. Maybe you could post more of your code?

Comment: The OP is adding the fragment to the built-in `android.R.id.content` `FrameLayout`, which is perfectly reasonable. It does mean that the layout XML file is superfluous, though.